# Changing background color of md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I am trying to implement `md-autocomplete` using Angular Materials.

How do I change the background color to white?

Approach 1: I tried to use `$mdThemingProvide` but it is changing the background of the input box.

Approach 2: I also tried to change color of the form.

Both the approaches didn't work. You can see the code for both below.

What i want to do is to change the background of the `md-autocomplete` form to white.

How do I do this?

Codes:

Aprroach 1:

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')

})
```

Approach 2:

```
<form ng-submit = "$event.preventDefault()"  style="background:White;">
```

The output can be [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLsOt.jpg).The arrow indicates the background whose color i want to change to white.

Comment: please show more of your HTML file since the problem is probably not with `md-autocomplete`

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the version of the Angular materials. Thanks